# TypeError: special() function missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting this error below...
I can't figure out what's wrong

This is sort of like a restaurant project that I'm working on and requires user input.

I'm kind of new to classes so I'd thought I try to improve on it.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 99, in <module>
    EdwardsCafe()
  File "main.py", line 31, in __init__
    food = EdwardsCafe.specials(special)
TypeError: specials() missing 1 required positional argument: 'special'
```

Whenever I run the program and try to input, I have a function in the class that specifically retrieves the specified value from a list of food items. However, the function says it is missing an argument.

Here  below so you can help me:

```
# some code here

class EdwardsCafe:
  def __init__(self):
    # some code
    write("We have: [1] - our specials, [2] - fast_foods, [3] - asian_foods")
    want = int(input())
    if want == 1:
      write(f"We have: {', '.join(specials)}")
      special = int(input())
      food = EdwardsCafe.specials(special)
    # some code
  def specials(self, special):
    self.special = special
    if self.special == 1:
      self.special = specials[0]
    elif self.special == 2:
      self.special = specials[1]
    elif self.special == 3:
      self.special = specials[2]
    return self.special
  # some code
```

Comment: What is `specials`?

Comment: You confuse class and instance methods. `EdwardsCafe.specials(special)` must be `self.specials(special)`.